# Broadcasting with shoe sockjs

Tags: node.js, sockjs

I am trying to setup a simple scenerio using shoe + dnode +sockjs and I do not know how to broadcast a message to all users connected to the web application.

Do you know if there is a function or method which manage this? or should it be make by "hand"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you have to roll it by "hand" as you say. Here is what I do:

**server.js:**

```
var shoe = require('shoe')

var connectedClients = {}
var conCount = 0

var sock = shoe(function(clientStream) {
  clienStream.id = conCount
  connectedClients[clientStream.id] = clientStream
  conCount += 1
})
```

somewhere else in your server-side program:

```
//write to all connected clients
Object.keys(connectedClients).forEach(function(cid) {
  var clientStream = connectedClients[cid]
  clientStream.write(yourData)
})
```

Note, you'll want to introduce additional logic to only write to connected clients, so you'll want to remove disconnected clients from `connectedClients`, something like `delete connectedClients[id]`.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Great! it's working perfectly. But I have an issue, I'm using dnode and shoe but when I send the message using .write directly, if the client has d.pipe(stream).pipe(d) (d = dnode) (stream = shoe) when the client receives the message the connection between server and client closes. But if I remove from client dnode it works perfectly.

Comment: I just glanced over the dnode docs, but I'm not sure. I've never used dnode =( You may want to create another SO question with some of your code and maybe someone with dnode experience could chime in.